# Prevent Kendo Grid from running two queries

Tags: c#, sql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Currently, when I attach a DataSource to a Kendo Grid, it runs **two** queries.

The First: is a `Count(*)` to create the correct number of pages and informing the user how many records exist.

The Second: is a `TOP` query based on how many rows per page will be displayed.

**My problem is** that even with `.Pageable(p => p.Enabled(false).Info(false))`  it is STILL running the Count(*) query.

The query I am running is very expensive and I would like to completely eliminate running of the first Count(*) query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate data into pages, you have to find a way to get the count from the server.  You just can't get around it.

As CodingWithSpike pointed out, displaying all the rows in a single page would probably take way more time that it would to get the count(*) so at this point you have few solutions.

A) You fix a maximum number of rows to be fetch in a single page.  Just make sure that the user is aware of this limitation.

B) If the number of record in your table is stable, you may cache the count on the server.

C) You could also cache the table data on the server side.  It would speed up the count and the data fetch.  However, you need to consider it's weight on server's memory and the fact that the data taken from the cache might not be up to date (you could consider refreshing data every X minutes).

If you want to go with option B or C, you'll probably have to implement your own Read logic (of the dataSource.transport object) in order to fetch cached data on the server.

**EDIT**

Knowing that you'll never get more than 100 rows I just came out with an hybrid solution.  Similar to A) except for the count that will be calculated on the client side:

D) Override the Read logic of the dataSource.transport in order to retrieve only the top 100 rows from the server.  The Read function has an option parameter object that can be used to return the data in a format that will be handled by the grid (ex: OData object).

Usually, the count returned by the OData object would be an inline count calculated on the server to let you know how many records match your filter.  In your case, it will always be the number of rows returned in your OData object so you'll be able to set it on the client side without any call to the server, before you call the success function.

Here's the [Kendo documentation about the transport.read](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read) (see the *set read as a function* section)

Comment: So this table is used for item mapping between multiple massive catalogs.  The idea is that I will only show the Top 100 results ever.  BUT we still want to leverage an IQueryable, so that if the user does a Kendo Filter on the Name, it still provides the top 100 results.  We did try to say `query.Take(100)` on the EF query behind the scenes, but then if you do a filter, it only filters on those 100 records pulled back, and not the entire catalog.

Comment: So when you filter your 100 rows, you may end up with an other set of 100 rows totally different from the original set?

Comment: Yea.  I'm trying to think about what you're saying, and how deep I'd have to get into the kendo sources to even rig this.  It might not be possible, I was just trying to cut the runtime down by HALF because this ranking query is expensive.

Basically I want to limit to the top 100, I'm fine with disabling paging, but keep their ability to use the Filters and Sorts to affect the entire datasource.

Comment: I spent several hours in the javascript files, following your direction above, but could not prevent the Count(*) query from running.

The problem for me seems to be inside the ToDataSourceResult() call.  Which is after all the javascript pieces are setup.

I appreciate the help, I just haven't found the solution heading in this direction at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off server paging on your dataSource (not just the grid). In javascript it would be the `DataSource.serverPaging` option. Not sure exactly what it is with MVC helpers.

However, I suspect that if getting a count(*) from your table takes too long, then you just have a LOT of rows, so turning off paging is going to make things worse because it will fetch all the rows and send them back to the client.